# React Native Navigaton After Login

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

help me please with one problem. I don't understand how to implement a redirect to home page after login. I need to refresh the app to do it.

In my app.js I have a const isSigned that takes a value from AsyncStorage, and when it isn't empty app should render 'home' component but it doesn't

Login works, I can get token and can save it to AsyncStorage.

app.js:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {ActivityIndicator, SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

import Login from './src/Login'
import Home from './src/Home'

export default function App() {
    const [isSigned, setIsSigned] = useState(false)

    useEffect(() => {
        AsyncStorage.getItem('token').then((value) => {
            if (value) {
                setIsSigned(true)
            }
        });
    }), []

    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <Drawer.Navigator>
                {isSigned ? (
                <>
                    <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
                </>
                ) : (
                <>
                    <Drawer.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
                </>
                )}
            </Drawer.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    );
}
```

login.js

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import {Text, View, SafeAreaView, TextInput, Button, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

export default function Login() {
    const [username, setUsername] = useState('')
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('')

    const storeToken = async (value) => {
        try {
            await AsyncStorage.setItem('token', value)
        }
    }

    function submitHandler() {
        const requestOptions = {
            body: JSON.stringify({
                "Username": username,
                "Password": password
            })
        };

        fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8080/login', requestOptions).then((response) => {
            return response.json();
        }).then((result) => {
            if (result !== '' && result !== 'error') {
                storeToken(result)
            }
        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.log("ERROR: ", error);
        })
    }

    return (
        <SafeAreaView>
            <TextInput
                defaultValue={username}
                onChangeText={text => setUsername(text)}
                placeholder={'Username'}
                style={styles.input}
            />

            <TextInput
                defaultValue={password}
                onChangeText={text => setPassword(text)}
                placeholder={'Password'}
                secureTextEntry={true}
                style={styles.input}
            />

            <Button
                title={'Login'}
                onPress={submitHandler}
            />

        </SafeAreaView>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 useEffect(() => {
        AsyncStorage.getItem('token').then((value) => {
            if (value) {
                setIsSigned(true)
            }
        });
    }), []
```

your useEffect code is wrong. It should be like this:

```
 useEffect(() => {
        AsyncStorage.getItem('token').then((value) => {
            if (value) {
                setIsSigned(true)
            }
        });
    },[isSigned])
```

This tells React, whenever `isSigned` changes, rerender the component. So you will not have to refresh the page, React will rerender automatically.

Any variable that defined inside the component or pass in to the component as a prop, must be placed inside dependency array of useEffect.

```
  useEffect(() => {
        AsyncStorage.getItem('token').then((value) => {
            if (value) {
                setIsSigned(true)
            }
        });
    },[])
```

in array [], we store the dependencies. We tell React, if any of the dependencies changes, rerender the component. If you just pass empty array [], this tells that useEffect will be called only once when the app is mounted. But if you modify the array:

```
   useEffect(() => {
        AsyncStorage.getItem('token').then((value) => {
            if (value) {
                setIsSigned(true)
            }
        });
    },[isSigned])
```

Answer (score 0):

tokens should NOT be stored in async storage, as it is security vulnerability

check out my answer to role-based authentication using react-hooks: [Role based authentication in React Native app using Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67178018/role-based-authentication-in-react-native-app-using-firebase/67178202#67178202)

Comment: Thank you, as i understand I have to use useReducer and call dispatch function in login.js after login?

Answer (score 0):

```
<Drawer.Navigator>
  //here
  {isSigned === true ? (
    <>
      <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
    </>
  ) : (
    <>
      <Drawer.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
    </>
  )}
</Drawer.Navigator>;
```

Comment: Try adding a button and console.log your variable: isSigned.
<Button
              title="TEST"
              onPress={() => console.log(isSigned)}
            />

Comment: yes, i know how to test it, but the problem is not in the value of isSigned. The problem is that I can't pass value to app.js from login.js