# React Native navigation won't refresh after login

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm having a similar problem to this post but there doesn't seem to be an answer: [React Native Navigaton After Login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67381170/react-native-navigaton-after-login)

after using the login screen I'm able to store the token and if I manually exit the app and start it again it does show me the lobby(home) screen but I need a way to go from the login screen straight to the home screen after logging in.

app.js

```
function App() {
  const [isSignedIn, setIsSignedIn] = useState(null);
  async function getData(){
    try {
      const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token')
      if(value !== null) {
        setIsSignedIn(value)
      }
    } catch(e) {
      console.log(e)
    }
  }
  getData()
  return (
    isSignedIn ? (
      <NavigationContainer>
          <StatusBar backgroundColor="#ffe6d9"/>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="LobbyScreen" component={LobbyScreen} options={{header: () => null}}/>
        <Stack.Screen name="LogActivityScreen" component={LogActivityScreen} options={{header: () => null}}/>
        <Stack.Screen name="PreviousLogsScreen" component={PreviousLogsScreen} options={{header: () => null}}/>
        <Stack.Screen name="AnnouncementsScreen" component={AnnouncementsScreen} options={{header: () => null}}/>
        <Stack.Screen name="GuidesScreen" component={GuidesScreen} options={{header: () => null}}/>
        <Stack.Screen name="CreditsScreen" component={CreditsScreen} options={{header: () => null}}/>
      </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    ) : (
      <NavigationContainer>
      <StatusBar backgroundColor="#ffe6d9"/>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="LoginScreen" component={LoginScreen} options={{header: () => null}}/>
        <Stack.Screen name="RegisterScreen" component={RegisterScreen} options={{header: () => null}}/>
      </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    )
  );
}
```

LoginScreen.js

```
export default function LoginScreen() {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('username');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('password');
  const [token, setToken] = useState(null);
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  const storeData = async (value) => {
    try {
      if (value == undefined) {
        alert('Invalid Login: Please Try Again')
      } else {
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('token', String(value))
        console.log('Data successfully saved')
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e)
    }
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.logoView}>
          <Image
              style={styles.logoSize}
              source={require('../assets/dls-logo.png')}
          />
        </View>
      <View style={styles.inputView}>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.inputWide}
          placeholder=" Username *Case-sensitive"
          onChangeText={(val) => setUsername(val)}
          keyboardType="default"
          autoCapitalize='none'
        />
        <TextInput
          style={styles.inputWide}
          placeholder=" Password"
          onChangeText={(val) => setPassword(val)}
          keyboardType="default"
          secureTextEntry={true}
          autoCapitalize='none'
        />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.buttonView}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.buttonTouchable}
          onPress={SubmitLogin}
          underlayColor='#fff'>
            <Text style={styles.baseText}>Log In</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.buttonTouchable}
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate('RegisterScreen')}
          underlayColor='#fff'>
            <Text style={styles.baseText}>Register</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>

  );

// Function for LogIn button
  async function SubmitLogin(){
    try {
      await fetch('http://192.168.100.11:100/api/login/', {
        method:'post',
        mode:'no-cors',
        headers: {
          'Accept':'application/json',
          'Content-Type':'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          username: username,
          password : password,
        })
      }).then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => storeData(JSON.stringify(response['token'])))
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e)
      Alert.alert('could not connect to website')
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are managing navigation is wrong. You have to create two stack navigators inside main navigator which will be used to manage authentication. Refer below code to do same.

```
    <NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef}>
        <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName='Splash'>
            <Stack.Screen name='Splash' options={{ headerShown: false }} component={Splash} />
            <Stack.Screen name='Auth' options={{ headerShown: false }} component={AuthStack} />
            <Stack.Screen name='Root' options={{ headerShown: false }} component={RootStack} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
```

Auth stack and Root stack will be like as below

```
const AuthStack = () => (
    <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name='Login' component={LoginScreen} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
);
const RootStack = () => (
    <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name='Home' component={HomeScreen} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
);
```

So this way your app will be initially load on splash screen and authentication flow will be managed on splash screen only. If token is available you can navigation user to RootStack else navigate user to the auth stack.

Thanks